# Share a partiton with Samba

Tags: 14.04, networking, partitioning, samba, drive

I am trying to share a partition so on my window computer they can see the drive name and how much space they used and have free. I read that people created the partition and then shared the folder inside on the partition but I want my window computer to be able to browse the network with partitions name and their space status.

So how can I share a partition on the network so people can see something like Pictures(P:) and then it will be able to show the drives space.

Answer (score 0):

Samba adds your folder to active directory, which is what Microsoft uses for network drives. Unfortunately, there is no good way to tell you how to configure the .conf or how to set it up, so I will point you to some useful resources.

Basically, you install Samba, and monkey around with the smb.conf until you get it working. A word of advice: back up your smb file!!

The community put together [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba) about the basics. It links to many useful documents.

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide) seemed like a very promising start, and gives you a good idea of what to do, but didn't work for me.

Finally, if that doesn't work, the docs on Samba are [here](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/toc.html). It is a book with the html of chapters.

If none of that gives you a start, I will update my post with more details.